# How to convert a CSV file to Parquet csv2parquet in python without using Spark and Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am new to python, My current requirement is, I need to convert a CSV file to a parquet format using the csv2parquet package.

I referred to https://pypi.org/project/csv2parquet/ but did not get much clarification. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After resolving some issues I used this code to convert a simple CSV file to parquet format, It works for me.

install the csv2parquet python package in your system.

```
pip install csv2parquet
```

Sample CSV file data

[employeees_detail.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5ksA.png)

**Python Code:**

```
import csv2parquet
from subprocess import run

command = 'csv2parquet "C:\\Users\\Dhandapani Sudhakar\\Desktop\\employees_detail.csv"'
run(command)
```

After the conversion the result parquet

[employees_detail.parquet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBj01.png)

or else you can directly execute the command in the command prompt

```
(csvtoparquetenv) A:\POCS\Project_Envs\csvtoparquetenv>csv2parquet "C:\Users\Dhandapani Sudhakar\Desktop\employees_detail.csv"
```